# Probability Simulation

Tags: probability, simulation, python

I was able to solve A but not sure about how to go about with the simulation.

let Xi = total number of times travelled via bus

x2 = total time to travel via car

prob it rains 20%

0.2 E(35+x1) + 80/100 E(x2)
0.2(40) + 0.8(30) = 32....please check as I am not sure and also assist with how to go about the simulation on python. Thank you

Suppose Alice takes the bus to work when the weather is clear, and
drives her car to work when it is raining. The probability of rain is 20%.
The wait time for the bus follows an exponential distribution with an
average wait time of 5 minutes. Once the bus arrives it always takes
35 minutes to get to work. When Alice drives to work, her commute
time is normally distributed with a mean of 30 and standard deviation
of 5.

(a) What is the theoretical mean of Alices commute time?

(b) Use simulations to estimate the mean and variance of Alices commute
time.

(c) Estimate by simulation the probability that the bus trip, including
the wait, is longer than the car trip.

Comment: Can you show us how you got to $0.2 E(35 + x_1)$ and so on? What are $x_1, x_2$?

Comment: added more info

Comment: @TobyMak i updated with more info

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. Chances are your question is not on-topic here if you are asking about the programming aspect, and not the mathematical aspect of the question. If you want your question answered here, you will have to be more specific, such as following the guidelines in [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).